# Replicação de banco de dados em tempo real

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, aplicação-web, replicação

Temos um cliente que precisa efetuar diversas consultas no banco de dados em um curto período de tempo, algo beirando 40 mil requisições em menos de 2 horas.

Criei um programa que faz a ponte entre as catracas do cliente e o nosso banco de dados para validar os acessos, porém o tempo de resposta é horrível e muitas vezes as catracas caem e ficam inoperantes (Catracas Henry 7x).

Preciso buscar uma forma de operar localmente, copiando os acessos do banco externo e disponibilizando os mesmos localmente em tempo real (ou quase). Porém, precisa ser de uma maneira segura e confiável e os dados dos acessos válidos precisam voltar para o servidor externo para sabermos quais ingressos foram usados.

O que me indicam?

**-------------------------------- EDIT --------------------------------**

**Catracas -> Banco de dados**

Código que faz a comunicação das catracas com o banco de dados:

```
public partial class CatracasVNJ : Form
{

    private Alternativo kernel7x; //Declarando Kernel
    private DBConnect ConexaoBanco; //Instanciando Kernel


    int eventIndex;


    delegate void ViewLine(TextBox textBox, string texto);


    public CatracasVNJ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        kernel7x = new Alternativo(); //Instanciando Kernel
        ConexaoBanco = new DBConnect(); //Instanciando Kernel

        kernel7x.OnRegistro += onlineRegistryEventHandler;
        kernel7x.OnProgresso += this.progressEventHandler;

        this.eventIndex = -1; 
    }


    /*=======================================================================
     * 
     *                      ROTINAS AUXILIARES
     * 
     *=======================================================================*/

    private short booltoshort(bool value)  {
        if (value) return 1; else return 0;
     }

    private void preeche(TextBox textBox, string texto)
    {
        addViewLine(texto);
        return;
    }

    private void addViewLine(String linha)
    {
        var data = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        txtMemo.AppendText(data + " - " + linha + "\r\n");
    }


    /*=======================================================================
     * 
     *                          ROTINAS DO FORM
     * 
     *=======================================================================*/

    public static string[] explode(string separator, string source)
    {
        return source.Split(new string[] { separator }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    }

    //BOTÕES DA INTERFACE
    private void btnIniciarCatracas_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // ações para preparar o botão e as rotas do inicia/para
        this.btnIniciarCatracas.Enabled = false;
        this.btnIniciarCatracas.Text = "PARAR";
        this.btnIniciarCatracas.Click -= new System.EventHandler(this.btnIniciarCatracas_Click);
        this.btnIniciarCatracas.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnPararCatracas_Click);

        // ação original do botão
        int i = 3000;
        string[] ListaIPS = ConexaoBanco.ListaCatracas(Int32.Parse("5"));
        foreach (string index in ListaIPS)
        {
            string[] resultado = explode(":", index);

            SComConfig _rConfig;
            _rConfig.IsCatraca = 0;

            _rConfig.ModoComunicacao = SModoComunicacao.cmcOnOff;
            _rConfig.TipoComunicacao = STipoComunicacao.ctcTcpIp;
            _rConfig.Tcp.Ip = resultado[0].ToString(); 
            _rConfig.Tcp.MAC = "";
            _rConfig.Tcp.Porta = i;
            _rConfig.Serial.NumeroRelogio = 1;

            int indexAux = kernel7x.get_AdicionaCardTcpIp(_rConfig.Tcp.Ip,
                _rConfig.Tcp.MAC, _rConfig.Tcp.Porta, false, _rConfig.ModoComunicacao);

            if (indexAux >= 0)
            {
                kernel7x.SetSincronizar(indexAux, false);

                addViewLine("Catraca adicionada: " + indexAux + " IP: " + resultado[0] + " Porta: " + i + "\n\r");
                listaCatracas.Items.Add("Catraca " + indexAux, 3);
            }
            else
            {
                addViewLine("Falha: " +
                    kernel7x.ErrorDescription(kernel7x.KernelLastError));
            }
            i++;
        }
        this.btnIniciarCatracas.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void btnPararCatracas_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.btnIniciarCatracas.Enabled = false;
        string[] ListaIPS = ConexaoBanco.ListaCatracas(Int32.Parse("5"));
        int i = 0;
        foreach (string index in ListaIPS)
        {
            string[] resultado = explode(":", index);
            kernel7x.get_RemoveCard(i);
            addViewLine("Catraca removida: " + resultado[0].ToString() + "\n\r");
            i++;
        }
        this.btnIniciarCatracas.Text = "INICIAR";
        this.btnIniciarCatracas.Click -= new System.EventHandler(this.btnPararCatracas_Click);
        this.btnIniciarCatracas.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnIniciarCatracas_Click);

        this.btnIniciarCatracas.Enabled = true;
    }


    private void escreveListaIPS(String linha)
    {
        //textBox1.AppendText(linha + "\r\n");
    }


    /*=======================================================================
     * 
     *                  TRATAMENTO DE EVENTOS DO KERNEL 
     * 
     *=======================================================================*/


    public void progressEventHandler(int pThreadIndex, int pByte, int pByteMax, int pBuffer, int pBufferMax)
    {

        Application.DoEvents();
    }

    private void onlineRegistryEventHandler(int pThreadIndex) {
        if (this.eventIndex == -1)
        {
            this.eventIndex = pThreadIndex;
            Thread regThread = new Thread(this.onlineRegistryEventHandlerThd);
            regThread.Start();

        }
    }

    private void onlineRegistryEventHandlerThd()
    {

        int pThreadIndex = eventIndex;


        ViewLine viewL = new ViewLine(this.preeche);

        try
        {
            //Recebe solicitação do kernel
            SRegistro registro;
            /*
             * Variáveis do Sregistros
             */
            bool Saida = false;
            bool MasterLiberou = false;
            bool FuncaoLiberou = false;
            bool AcessoNegado = false;


            //txtMemo.Invoke(viewL, txtMemo, "Pedido de acesso recebido : " + pThreadIndex);

            //Seu tratamento de acesso e ponto
            SResposta resposta = new SResposta();

            //Recebe do relógio ou catraca em tempo real
            this.kernel7x.RegistroOn(pThreadIndex,
                out registro.NumeroRelogio,
                out registro.Funcao,
                out registro.Matricula,
                out registro.DataHora,
                out registro.Flag,
                out Saida,
                out MasterLiberou,
                out FuncaoLiberou,
                out AcessoNegado,
                out registro.Tipo.FonteEntrada,
                out registro.Tipo.TipoNegado);
            registro.Tipo.Saida = booltoshort(Saida);
            registro.Tipo.MasterLiberou = booltoshort(MasterLiberou);
            registro.Tipo.FuncaoLiberou = booltoshort(FuncaoLiberou);
            registro.Tipo.AcessoNegado = booltoshort(AcessoNegado);

            resposta.Mensagem = "***** VNJ ***** Acesso Liberado!";
            resposta.Tempo = Convert.ToByte(1);

            int catraca = pThreadIndex;
            int arena;
            int.TryParse("5", out arena);

            long acessoConvertido;
            var acesso = registro.Matricula;
            try
            {
                acessoConvertido = Convert.ToInt64(acesso);

                //txtMemo.Invoke(viewL, txtMemo, "Catraca : " + catraca + "Acesso : " + acessoConvertido + "Arena : " + arena);
                string[] RespostaAcesso = ConexaoBanco.LiberaCatracaUnificada(catraca, arena, acessoConvertido);

                if (Int32.Parse(RespostaAcesso[0]) == 0)
                {
                    kernel7x.RespostaOn(pThreadIndex, SAcessoOnline.canLibEntrada, resposta.Mensagem, resposta.Tempo);
                    // Retorno pro programa
                    txtMemo.Invoke(viewL, txtMemo, "Acesso LIBERADO para : " + acesso);
                } 
                else
                {
                    kernel7x.RespostaOn(pThreadIndex, SAcessoOnline.canNegado, RespostaAcesso[1].ToString(), resposta.Tempo);
                    // Retorno pro programa
                    txtMemo.Invoke(viewL, txtMemo, "Acesso bloqueado para : " + acesso);
                }
            }  

            catch (OverflowException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Esta fora da range permitida para este tipo de variável.", acesso);
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Não foi possível converter.");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
           txtMemo.Invoke(viewL, txtMemo, "Exceção: " + e.Message);
        }

        eventIndex = -1;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TESTA STORED PROCEDURE
        string[] RespostaAcesso = ConexaoBanco.LiberaCatracaUnificada(1, Int32.Parse("5"), 1);

        addViewLine(RespostaAcesso[0].ToString() + "\n\r");
        addViewLine(RespostaAcesso[1].ToString() + "\n\r");

        /// SEPARADOR //////////////////////////////////////
        txtMemo.AppendText("=========================================================== \n");
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////

        // TESTA CONVERSÃO DE VARIAVEL
        long acessoConvertido;
        var acesso = "000000088973229041253";
        try
        {
            acessoConvertido = Convert.ToInt64(acesso);
            addViewLine("Convertio com sucesso: " + acessoConvertido);
            Console.WriteLine("Converted the {0} acesso '{1}' to the {2} acesso {3}.", acesso.GetType().Name, acesso, acessoConvertido.GetType().Name, acessoConvertido);
        }
        catch (OverflowException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Esta fora da range permitida para este tipo de variável.", acesso);
        }
        catch (FormatException) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A {0} acesso '{1}' não está disponível para conversão.", acesso.GetType().Name, acesso);
        }

        // TESTA COMUNICAÇÃO COM A CATRACA
        string[] ListaIPS = ConexaoBanco.ListaCatracas(Int32.Parse("5"));
        int i = 0;
        foreach (string index in ListaIPS)
        {
            txtMemo.AppendText("=========================================================== \n");
            //
            kernel7x.RecebeTipoCatraca(i, out SStatusGiro pStatusGiro, out byte pTempoLiberacao);
            kernel7x.RecebeConfigDSP(i, out int pNivelSeguranca, out int pVelocidade, out int p2, out int p3, out bool p4, out bool pb);

            addViewLine("Catraca número: " + i);
            addViewLine("-");
            addViewLine("Status giro: " + pStatusGiro + "   Tempo de liberação: " + pTempoLiberacao);
            addViewLine("Nivel de segurança: " + pNivelSeguranca + "       Status: " + pb);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

**Função que conecta no banco**

Código da função que é usada para validar o acesso do bilhete ou carteirinhas nas catracas:

```
        //////////////////////////////////////////////
    // LiberaCatracaUnificada( Nrdispositivo , arena , acesso );
    //
    // Parametros:
    // @ pThreadIndex: Número da catraca
    // @ Arena: Número de identificação da arena
    // @ Acesso: Número do ingresso ou mifare
    //
    // Retornos da função:
    // [0] = Resposta da Stored Procedures
    // [1] = Mensagem de resposta da Stored Procedure
    //////////////////////////////////////////////
    public string[] LiberaCatracaUnificada(int pThreadIndex, int arena, long acesso)
    {
        // Pega o NrDispositivo da catraca
        var ListaIPs = ListaCatracas(arena);
        string[] IP = ListaIPs[pThreadIndex].TrimStart(':').Split(':');
        int NrDispositivo = Int32.Parse(IP[1]);

        // Pega a data atual
        var data = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        // Prepara a query
        string query = "CALL permite_acesso('" + arena + "', '" + acesso + "', '" + NrDispositivo + "', '" + data + "')";

        // Abre conexão com o db
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                string[] retornoStoredProcedure = new string[2];
                retornoStoredProcedure[0] = dataReader["RESPOSTA"].ToString();
                retornoStoredProcedure[1] = dataReader["MENSAGEM"].ToString();

                dataReader.Close();
                this.CloseConnection();

                return retornoStoredProcedure;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string[] resposta = new string[] { "99", "FALHA AO CONSULTAR STORED PROCEDURE" };
            return resposta;
        }
        string[] resposta1 = new string[] { "98", "FALHA ENCONTRADA" };
        return resposta1;
    }
```

**-------------------------------- EDIT 2 --------------------------------**

Obrigado pelo retorno, então amigo a princípio não é possível trocarmos o banco de dados no momento, já sentimos a necessidade de troca-lo mas devido a vários fatores não é possível fazer isso no momento.

Eu estava pensando em fazer algo parecido com o que comentário acima, criar uma espécie de fila e ir recebendo os dados e após o jogo envia-los de volta ao servidor.

Porém, o cenário ideal era trabalharmos totalmente online, mas se for possível criar de uma maneira eficaz essa "fila" pode resolver o problema eu acho.

Vou postar abaixo o código da Stored Procedure e a arquitetura da tabela dos acessos.

**Stored Procedure**

```
BEGIN
DECLARE RESPOSTA INT DEFAULT -1;
DECLARE _tpingresso_id INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE _data INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE _tituloso_id INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE _ingressocategoria_id INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE _acesso_id INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE _acesso_status INT DEFAULT -1;
DECLARE _titulosociedade_acessostatus varchar(10) default '';
DECLARE _evento_id INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE _entrada_nome VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE _catraca_id INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE _entrada_id INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE _titulosociedade_id INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE _observacao varchar(200) default '';
DECLARE _num_acessos_permitidos int;
DECLARE _num_acessos_atual int;

SET _acesso_id = 0; 
set _catraca_id = 0;
set _num_acessos_permitidos = 1;

-- BUSCA DADOS DO EVENTO
select evento.evento_id into _evento_id from  evento WHERE DATA_REF BETWEEN evento.iniAcesso AND evento.fimAcesso AND evento.arena_id = ARENA limit 1;

-- SE EXISTIR O EVENTO
IF(_evento_id > 0) THEN

    -- BUSCA DADOS DA CATRACA
    SELECT arena_catraca.catraca_id, trim(arena_entrada.nome) into _catraca_id, _entrada_nome FROM arena_catraca inner join arena_entrada on arena_entrada.entrada_id = arena_catraca.entrada_id WHERE arena_catraca.nrDispositivo = CATRACA AND arena_catraca.arena_id = ARENA limit 1;

    -- SE ENCONTRADA A CATRACA
    IF(_catraca_id > 0) THEN 

        -- BUSCA ACESSO DO TIPO INGRESSO
        SELECT acesso_id INTO _acesso_id FROM acesso WHERE acesso.chaveAcesso = CODIGO and acesso.evento_id = _evento_id order by status limit 1;

            -- select count(*) into _num_acessos_atual from acesso where acesso.evento_id = _evento_id and acesso.chaveAcesso = CODIGO limit 1; 

        -- BUSCA DADOS DE SOCIEDADE
        IF (COALESCE(_acesso_id,0) <= 0) THEN

            -- BUSCA A CARTEIRINHA
            SELECT titulosociedade.tituloso_id,tpsocio.tpingresso_id
            INTO _tituloso_id, _tpingresso_id
            FROM titulosocar
            INNER JOIN titulosociedade on titulosocar.tituloso_id = titulosociedade.tituloso_id
            INNER JOIN tpsocio on tpsocio.tpsocio_id = titulosociedade.tpsocio_id
            WHERE titulosocar.nroMifare = CODIGO
            LIMIT 1;

            IF(_tituloso_id > 0) THEN 
                -- INSERE ACESSO DO SÓCIO
                insert into acesso (evento_id, tpingresso_id, tituloso_id, chaveAcesso, entidade_id, nroCarteira,status) 
                values(_evento_id, _tpingresso_id, _tituloso_id, CODIGO, 10, CODIGO,0);

                -- SELECIONA O ACESSO INSERIDO
                SELECT acesso_id INTO _acesso_id FROM acesso WHERE acesso.chaveAcesso = CODIGO and acesso.evento_id = _evento_id order by status limit 1;

            END IF;
        END IF;

        IF (COALESCE(_acesso_id,0) > 0) THEN



            -- BUSCA STATUS DO ACESSO
            select distinct case when coalesce(titulosociedade.statusAcesso,'L') in ('L') then coalesce(acesso.status,0) else 5 end, acesso.tpingresso_id
            into  _acesso_status, _tpingresso_id
            from acesso
            left join titulosociedade on titulosociedade.tituloso_id = acesso.tituloso_id
            where acesso.acesso_id = _acesso_id;

            -- VERIFICA O STATUS DO ACESSO
            if (coalesce(_acesso_status,-1) >= 0 ) THEN

                CASE
                    -- LIBERADO
                    WHEN _acesso_status = 0 THEN 
                        SET _entrada_id = 0;

                        -- BUSCA ENTRADA - SE PERMITIDO O ACESSO RETORNA UM INTEIRO
                        SELECT distinct arena_catraca_setor.entrada_id
                        INTO _entrada_id
                        FROM ( SELECT arena_catraca.* FROM arena_catraca WHERE arena_catraca.nrDispositivo = CATRACA AND arena_catraca.arena_id = ARENA) arena_catraca
                        inner join arena_entrada on arena_entrada.entrada_id = arena_catraca.entrada_id
                        inner join arena_catraca_setor on arena_catraca_setor.catraca_id = arena_catraca.catraca_id and arena_catraca_setor.setor_id in (select setor_id from arena_setortpingresso where tpingresso_id = _tpingresso_id);

                        -- SE ACESSO PERMITIDO
                        IF(coalesce(_entrada_id,0) > 0 ) THEN
                            SET _observacao = CONCAT( _observacao,'Acesso Permitido');
                            SET RESPOSTA = 0;

                            update acesso set status = 1 where acesso_id = _acesso_id;
                        -- SE ACESSO NEGADO PARA ESSE SETOR
                        else
                            SET _observacao = CONCAT(_observacao,'Acesso negado para esse setor');
                            SET RESPOSTA = 15;
                        end if;

                    -- TENTATIVA DUPLICADA DE ACESSO
                    WHEN _acesso_status = 1 THEN 
                        set _observacao = CONCAT(_observacao, 'Tentantiva duplicada de acesso');
                        set RESPOSTA = 1;
                    WHEN _acesso_status = 5 THEN 
                        set _observacao = CONCAT(_observacao, 'Pendências Financeiras');
                        set RESPOSTA = 5;
                    ELSE 
                        set _observacao = CONCAT(_observacao, 'Erro de leitura');
                        set RESPOSTA = 99;
                END CASE;
            ELSE
                SET _observacao = CONCAT( _observacao,'Status de Acesso inválido!');
                SET RESPOSTA = 22;
            END IF;
        ELSE
            IF(CODIGO = 3579281461 OR CODIGO = 82282900 OR CODIGO = 82282596 OR CODIGO = 82282580 OR CODIGO = 82282868 OR CODIGO = 82282564 OR CODIGO = 82282852 OR CODIGO = 82282548 OR CODIGO = 82282884) THEN
                INSERT INTO outrosacessos(evento_id) VALUES(_evento_id);
                SET _observacao = CONCAT( _observacao,'ACESSO MASTER');
                SET RESPOSTA = 0;
            ELSE
                SET _observacao = CONCAT( _observacao,'Acesso Não Encontrado!');
                SET RESPOSTA = 22;
            END IF;
        END IF;

        IF(_acesso_id > 0 and _catraca_id > 0 and _evento_id > 0) THEN
            insert into acesso_log (acesso_id, observacao, data, catraca_id, evento_id, resultado) values(_acesso_id, _observacao, DATA_REF, _catraca_id, _evento_id, RESPOSTA);
        END IF;
    ELSE
        set _observacao = 'Catraca não encontrada!';
        set RESPOSTA = 20;
    END IF;
ELSE
    set _observacao = 'Evento não encontrado!';
    set RESPOSTA = 20;
END IF;

SELECT RESPOSTA RESPOSTA, _observacao MENSAGEM, coalesce(_acesso_id,0) ACESSO_ID;
```

**Tabela**

> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `acesso`;
>   CREATE TABLE `acesso` (
>     `acesso_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>     `tpingresso_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>     `tpcategoria_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>     `voucherkey` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>     `chaveAcesso` bigint(200) DEFAULT NULL,
>     `pedidoiteming_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>     `entidade_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>     `cadeira_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>     `operador_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>     `dtUtilizacao` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
>     `nroCarteira` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>     `valor` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
>     `vlDesconto` decimal(15,4) DEFAULT NULL,
>     `vlTaxa` decimal(15,4) DEFAULT NULL,
>     `vlTotal` decimal(15,4) DEFAULT NULL,
>     `status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>     `evento_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>     `tituloso_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>     `tipoGeracao` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
>     `motivo` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
>     `nroMifare` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
>     `caixa_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>     `pedidoitem_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>     `ingressocategoria_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY (`acesso_id`),
>     KEY `tpingresso_id` (`tpingresso_id`),
>     KEY `entidade_id` (`entidade_id`),
>     KEY `cadeira_id` (`cadeira_id`),
>     KEY `evento_id` (`evento_id`),
>     CONSTRAINT `acesso_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`tpingresso_id`) REFERENCES `arena_tipoingresso` (`tpingresso_id`),
>     CONSTRAINT `acesso_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`entidade_id`) REFERENCES `entidade` (`entidade_id`),
>     CONSTRAINT `acesso_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`cadeira_id`) REFERENCES `arena` (`arena_id`),
>     CONSTRAINT `acesso_ibfk_7` FOREIGN KEY (`evento_id`) REFERENCES `evento` (`evento_id`)
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4624 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

Comment: Coloque mais informações na sua pergunta, ela esta muito ampla.

Comment: não acho que seja o caso de replicação em tempo real, talvez um cache local e uma fila pra ir atualizando os que já foram utilizados. Acho que é tranquilo de fazer até porque a solicitação é muito pequena. Mas coloque mais informações sobre o projeto

Comment: se puder, coloque a lógica que você fez na ponte entre as catracas e seu banco de dados

Comment: Obrigado à todos, irei atualizar com mais informações!

Comment: Atualizado pessoal. Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Você precisa fazer uma análise do schema do banco. As tabelas estão indexadas? As referências são fortes? Veja também se o *pooling* de conexões está configurado direito.

Comment: Como posso faço essa análise? Bem como esses outros testes que você mencionou? Grato.

Answer (score 1):

40.000 requisições em duas horas não é muito, mesmo que fosse em 15 minutos, seria cerca de 50 requisições por segundo.

Então acredito que caiba muito espaço para melhorias no seu banco, analise a sua estrutura de dados, algum índice que esteja faltando, alguma restrição desnecessária.

Se realmente precisa trabalhar com um sistema distribuído, tenho duas recomendações, a primeira é utilizando o [`SQLite-sync`](http://sqlite-sync.com) ou partir para um NoSQL que tenha suporte para sincronização como o [`Realm`](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet), Mas de ante mão, você terá que implementar alterações na sua estrutura, como por exemplo utilizar `Guid` ao invés de `Int32` para as suas chaves.

Por fim, se desempenho é realmente importante para você, analise à possibilidade de utilizar um `PostgresQL` no lugar do `MySQL`.

Uma outra recomendação, caso posa utilizar o `.net 4.6.1`, é adotar o `Entity Framework Core 2.0` como `ORM`, uma vez que terá de utilizar o `Sqlite` no cliente e `PostgresQL/MySQL` na base centralizada, o `EF Core 2.0` poderá lher ajudar com o particionamento das consultas, ao aplicar filtros globais, assim como com à `perfomance` do sistema, ao utilizar consultas pre-compiladas.